# Including C library in Go triggers syntax and type errors

Tags: c, docker, go, cgo

I am writing a Go program that needs to import a C library. The library is a 3rd party library so I only have the header files.
While working with this library in C, there are no compilation or syntax errors, however, when building my Go/cgo program I am seeing *pages* of errors to this effect:

```
#11 0.473 ./vendor/path/to/lib/base.h:235:31: error: stray '##' in program
#11 0.473 ./vendor/path/to/lib/base.h:235:46: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
#11 0.473 ./vendor/path/to/lib/common.h:13:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '#pragma'
#11 0.473 ./vendor/path/to/lib/init.h:227:52: error: unknown type name 'InitOptionsType'
#11 0.473 ./vendor/path/to/lib/init.h:271:59: error: unknown type name 'PlatformOptionsType'
...
```

At first, I was seeing these errors on Windows and blamed GCC issues. Now, however, I am building this in a Docker container running Alpine Linux and with GCC installed.

Dockerfile for reference:

```
FROM golang:alpine
ENV APP_NAME hello-world
# install gcc
RUN apk add build-base
WORKDIR /home/helloworld
# copy and build program across
ADD vendor/ ./vendor/
COPY main.go .
COPY go.mod .
RUN go build -o /go/app
```

GCC version

```
gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

And finally, my Go code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// #cgo CFLAGS: -Ivendor/path/to/lib/ -g -Wall
// #include "vendor/path/to/lib/sdk.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

Without the #include, the program builds and runs perfectly.

For further illustration, here are the areas of code that were highlighted by the errors I gave :

```
#define MY_STRUCT(struct_name, struct_def)           \

    EXTERN_C typedef struct _tag ## struct_name {     \ // stray '##' in program
                                                        // & expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token

        MY_PASTE struct_def                          \

    } struct_name
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: `base.h` contains a macro that needs to be processed by the C preprocessor first. The C library should be compiled already, are you putting the source within a Go package?

Comment: @JimB Can you clarify what you mean by "are you putting the source within a Go package"?

Comment: Are the C source files in a go package directory? It looks like the cgo tool is trying use the file before the macros are expanded.

Comment: @JimB The library also comes with a .lib, a .dll and a .dylib - should I be including one of those? Edit: The C source files are under ./vendor as well

Comment: The contents of vendor should only include what is put there by `go mod vendor`. If there are compiled shared libraries, then yes, those are what you need.

Comment: Also, because of your « CFLAGS » line, your include shouldn’t be just: « #include<sdk.h> » ?

Comment: @mgagnon JimB was right, importing the .h alone doesn't take into account the preprocessor requirements