# Importing C library into Go with only headers, .lib/.dll/.dylib

Tags: c, go, cgo

The title basically says it all.

I need to import a 3rd party C SDK into a Go script which will be running on Alpine Linux (in a Docker container).

I have access to:

- The header files (.h)
- the .dll file that represents the SDK
- the .lib file that represents the SDK
- the .dylib file that represents the SDK
- the .so file that represents the SDK

I tried setting up the script this way:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// #cgo CFLAGS: -Ivendor/path/to/lib/ -g -Wall
// #include "vendor/path/to/lib/sdk.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

However, I cannot import the header files this way because there are preprocessor definitions that are not handled in this scenario, [see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71424909/including-c-library-in-go-triggers-syntax-and-type-errors).

What are my options in this case?

Thanks!

Edit: Would building my own C program that imports the functions from the .so and then including that in my Go script instead work?

Comment: You need to point it at the final header built for the library, not the header containing macros. CGO is not going to build the library, it just needs the final header to link it.

Comment: It looks (further inspection pending) as if all the .h files contain macros. I'm not expecting CGo to build anything ,but I'm running out of ideas on how I can call these library functions rom Go